# Do I need to ask for the artist's permission every session to access his Facebook page status updates?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I need to access status updates of an artist page to display as feed on my website.
So everytime a user accesses the artist' space on my website, he sees the artist's status feed in a tab.
Do I need to ask for the artist's permission every session? That would not be practical I guess.

Thanks

Comment: This is more a question of a) Read the terms and conditions & b) legal/copyright - **not** programming!

Comment: @SteveBarnes... I know... Its just with all the access token, permission, I got a little confused. How long is an access token valid though??

Comment: This has not code, it is about legal & copyright.

Comment: It's not really about legal or copyright. It is a bit general tough. But I must admit that the facebook doc's aren't always the most easy to peruse trough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to ask permission once, when the user logins for the first time.

If you use the client side JS SDK, that is really all you need to worry about. The access_token will be automatically refreshed by the SDK whenever needed. The user only needs to be logged in to facebook, no action is required.

You will most likely be using the JS SDK.
So unless you use a manual server side oauth flow, see below:

If you use a manual server side oauth flow you usually get a `short-term` access_token that is valid for 2 hours after the user logs in for the first time.
You can request a long term access_token by sending a request to `oauth/access_token` with some additional parameters:

See here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

This long lived access_token is valid indefinitely, **but may expire at ANY moment.**

Reasons could be:

- user password change
- user logout
- use de-authorizes app
- ...

So you are to just reuse the `access_token` whenever you want to interact with the users facebook account ( you don't have to ask them to log in again).

But as soon as your `access_token` becomes invalid, you have to  update the acces_token by sending the user trough the oauth flow again.

Comment: Thanks.. Exactly what i was looking for.. Finally found the right section to read in the facebook documentation too...